# Validate jquery uploadify request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, uploadify

I used jquery uploadify plugin but I don't know how can I validate my form request, because even `SessionId` is a new id, I want to ensure the request comes from my form not another sites.

Thanks.

Comment: You're looking for same site request checks? Look into request anti-forgery tokens. There are built-in tools for MVC, but I think you'll have to find a library or write your own for WebForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you generating the form or is the form coming from another site?

If it's from your site take the time, generate a hash of it using a seed & append that to the time (as a string). Put the resultant base64 encoded string in your form.

Now when someone submits the form, parse the string, read the time & check it's within an acceptable range (say 30mins) & that the hash is valid (ie it's not been tampered with). Since only you know the seed, no-one else can spoof your form.

if the form is coming from another source, you could use this technique and share the seed between both sites or do a more complicated API key type approach.

This technique may not be perfect (I make no guarantee that it is), but a little googling will show you similar techniques.